# Writing output of command to variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution

I would like to put the output of a command into a variable. As far as I know, you have to use either of these:

```
variable=$(command)
variable=`command`
```

The following should work from my point of view:

```
for i in $(ls -1); do
    modTime=$(/usr/gnu/bin/date -r $i +$F)
    echo $modTime
done
```

I tried backticks as well; nothing changes. If it is important, it's a bash shell.

Comment: Should be like that modTime='/usr/gnu/bin/date -r $i +%F' with backticks in place of quote

Answer (score 1):

First, never parse the output of `ls`. The output is considered to be human readable, and not designed for parsing. It is much better to simply loop over the globbing, as I will show below.

The actual issue was that you used `$F` rather than `%F`. The former would have been an empty variable, and so it the date command would not have had any output. So, here is the modified command:

```
for i in ./*; do
    modTime="$(/usr/gnu/bin/date -r "$i" +%F)"
    echo "$modTime"
done
```

However, a single `find` command should do what you want:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td\n"
```

Comment: Even when using a shell glob, you need to quote the variable `"$i"` to stop the `date` command  breaking on whitespace, I think

Comment: Technically, the globbing should escape spaces, etc., but you are correct that it is good practice to always quote strings, and even inside the other quotes. I'll update that.

Comment: No need to quote the _RHS_ of variable assignment. So you don't need the outer quotes but (unless you're using `zsh`) you have to quote `$i` - that's parameter expansion, there's no such thing as _globbing escaping spaces_...